Uniform dynamics in quantum mechanics
I've found in the book "Quantum Processes System & Information" of Benjamin Schumacher the following definition of "uniform dynamic":

it often happens that the basic dynamical laws governing a quantum
system do not change over time. When this is true, we say that the
system experiences uniform dynamic

This definition takes on a fundamental role in time evolutions (so for Schrödinger's equation), I read from the book

Every informationally isolated quantum system with uniform dynamic has
a basis of stationary states

I am wondering whether the concept of uniform dynamics can be generalized for variables other than time, such as rotations. Can we then arrive at similar conclusions regarding the presence of stationary states for rotations, assuming a uniform dynamic condition for rotations?

So the basis of stationary states (in a time independent system) is interpreted as the eigenstates of the operator characterizing a unitary evolution. For time evolution, this would be the (time independent) Hamiltonian eigenstates. For rotations, I believe you could look at angular momentum operators eigenstates.

I have to wonder why the textbook author feels a need to redefine language that has been used in physics for almost a century. What's wrong with saying "time independent potential" or "time independent Schroedinger equation"? I also don't understand what "informationally isolated" is supposed to mean. One can't prepare a system and one can't read it out without making it open to the environment and without changing "the information" that we have about it.

With "informationally isolated" it means that the system is not measured, so in this case go under unitary evolution, it use "informationally isolated" instead of "closed" for unitary evolution
